# sweetAlert preventDefault and return true

Tags: jquery, return, preventdefault, sweetalert

I tried [sweeAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) plugin, which works perfectly, but I cant figure out how to do default stuff after confirm.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function handleDelete(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover the delaer again!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    },
    function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            return true;
        }
    });
};
});
```

and the button

```
 <a href="{plink delete! $row->id_dealers}" class="delete" onclick"handleDelete(event);">&nbsp;</a>
 //{plink delete! $row->id_dealers} Nette -> calls php delete handler
```

I also tried `unbind()` and `off()` instead of `return false`, doesnt work.
Earlier I used `confirm()` with `return true` and `return false`in `onclick` attribute, it works, but it looks awful.

Comment: the event has already been stopped because of `e.preventDefault();` so *default stuff* will no longer work.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I'm asking here for solution :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.delete').on('click',function(e, data){
    if(!data){
      handleDelete(e, 1);
    }else{
      window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    }
  });
});
function handleDelete(e, stop){
  if(stop){
    e.preventDefault();
    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You will not be able to recover the delaer again!",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete!",
      closeOnConfirm: false
    },
    function (isConfirm) {
      if (isConfirm) {
        $('.delete').trigger('click', {});
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Here is a demo **http://jsbin.com/likoza/1/edit?html,js,output**

Another way is the use a form instead of a `href`.

The markup would look like this

```
<form action="">
  <input type="submit" ...... />
</form>
```

and instead of `window.location = $(this).attr('href');` you can just say `form.submit()`

---

## Update

If there are multiple elements on the page then trigger can be used like this

```
$(e.target).trigger('click', {});
```

Here is a demo **http://output.jsbin.com/likoza/2**

Comment: For those who have multiple links with the same class don't forget that $('.delete').trigger('click', {}); does not refer to the clicked element, but to all elements with class="delete".

Comment: @kikinet If there are multiple elements then you can use `$(e.target).trigger('click', {});`. Updated my answer with another demo.

Comment: For me, using the trigger action on `function (isConfirm)` results in a loop with the delete button. I changed the action with `form.submit();` and worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it:

```
$('.delete').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentElement = $(this);

    swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover the delaer again!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete!",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        },
        function () {
            window.location.href = currentElement.attr('href');
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i did it:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitDelete").on("click", function () {
        swal({
            title: "Delete important stuff?",
            text: "That seem like your deleting some important Item. Are you sure?",
            dangerMode: true,
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true
        }).then((confirmed) => {
            if (confirmed) {
                $(function () {
                    $('#DeleteForm').submit(); // manully submit });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the event occurrence you can use a trigger event with a parameter. This means you can use it on form or link or basically any event:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.link').click(function (ev, param) {
    if (param == 'approved') { // User approved
      return true; // Not preventing default because user approved
    }

    // stopping event, before might triggering the event again, depends on user confirming 
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();

    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You will not be able to recover the delaer again!",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete!",
      closeOnConfirm: false
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
        // Triggering the event again, but with approve flag
        $(this).trigger('click', 'approved');
      }
    })
  })
});
```