# C#, MVC Confirmation Delete Dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, sweetalert

At the beggining i would like to sorry for my bad English skills. I create web app using MVC with Entity Framework. I would like to create a customized confirmation dialog, when user try to delete record from table. Confirmation works  when i use standard confirmation dialog "return confirm('Are you sure?')". But i would like to use a customized confirmation dialog like sweet alert from bootstrap or something similar.

Delete method in Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        DiabeticControl diabeticControl = db.DiabeticControls.Find(id);
        db.DiabeticControls.Remove(diabeticControl);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");


    }
```

Table in view:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Result)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Time)</td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "DiabeticControls",  new { id = item.Id }))
                    {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default xs-margin" })
                            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default xs-margin" })
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger xs-margin delete" >Delete</button>

                    }
                </div>
                @{
                    ViewBag.Key = item.Id;
                 }


            </td>

            <td>@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.UserId)</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

I have found the simple problem in :   [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418718/sweetalert-preventdefault-and-return-true)  but it doesn't work in my project.

And my JavaScript:

@section Scripts{

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $('.delete').on('click', function (e, data) {
            if (!data) {
                handleDelete(e, 1);
            } else {
                window.location = $(this).attr("@Url.Action("DiabeticControls")");
            }
        });

    });


    function handleDelete(e, stop) {
        if (stop) {
            e.preventDefault();
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "You will not be able to recover the delaer again!",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete!",
                closeOnConfirm: false
            },
            function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    swal("Deleted", "", "success");
                    $('.delete').trigger('click', {});
                }
                else {
                    swal("Cancelled", "", "error");
                }
            });
        }
    };





</script>
```

}

Comment: Please post your JavaScript

Comment: Ok, I added JavaScript to main post ;)

Comment: I see dialog, but even i click yes, nothing gonna happen.

Comment: `closeOnConfirm: false` might have something to do with that.

Comment: No, i tried to delete this line of code or set it to true, but unfortunelly it doesn't work. But od course thank you very much for try to help me ;)

Comment: In this case we have multiple buttons which have delete class. So, i think we can't do it this way: $('.delete').trigger('click', {});

Comment: I wouldn't add multiple forms in my view for each record, I think what you should do is one view for all, and on confirmation, set the id of that row object, and submit the form using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks a lot for help, but i found the solution. Problem was in my libraries  which i attached. I replace it with different versions of jquery.js, sweetalert.css and sweetalert.js, and i customized my JavaScript based on solution from this post: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418718/sweetalert-preventdefault-and-return-true)

My JavaScript:

@section Scripts{

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.delete').on('click', function (e, data) {
            if (!data) {
                handleDelete(e, 1);
            } else {
                window.location = $(this).attr('href');
            }
        });



    });


    function handleDelete(e, stop) {
        if (stop) {
            e.preventDefault();
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "You will not be able to recover the delaer again!",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete!",
                closeOnConfirm: false
            },
            function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    $(e.target).trigger('click', {});
                }
            });
        }
    };





</script>
```

}